# Ormlite + PredicateBuilder "variable referenced from scope '', but it is not defined"

Tags: linq, orm, predicate, ormlite-servicestack, predicatebuilder

When I attempt the following:

```
   public List<MatterViewModel> ReturnMatchingMatters(IEnumerable<string> matterNames)
    {
        var filter = PredicateBuilder.True<tblMatter>();
        filter = x => matterNames.Any(mattername => mattername.ToLowerInvariant() == x.Matter.ToLowerInvariant());

        return this.dal.DB.GetList<MatterViewModel>(OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.ExpressionVisitor<tblMatter>().Where(filter).ToSelectStatement());
    }
```

I receive the error:

`variable 'x' of type '[...]tblMatter' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined`
([...] mine)

Essentially, what I'm trying to accomplish is to have the predicate return true if the matter string is contained within any of the matters.

What am I missing? Do I need to do some sort of foreach with a temp variable?

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but `var filter = PredicateBuilder.True<tblMatter>();` is dead code, because you immediately re-assign the filter variable. I would try to remove noise first, i.e. directly put the lambda in the Where.

Comment: Is this ormlite-servicestack?  I've updated the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code accomplishes what I need to do, though might not be the prettiest.

```
    public List<string> ReturnMatchingMatters(IEnumerable<string> matterNames)
    {

        var filter = PredicateBuilder.True<tblMatter>();
        filter = x => Sql.In(x.Matter, matterNames);

        SqlExpressionVisitor<tblMatter> ev = OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.ExpressionVisitor<tblMatter>();

        ev.Select("select Matter from tblmatter");
        ev.Where(filter);

        return this.dal.DB.GetList<string>(ev.ToSelectStatement());
    }
```